# Encrypting login data in a c# WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a number of projects developed in WinForms.  Despite looking around on SO and other areas I've not really found a satisfactory answer.

The projects make use of the `app.config` and are deployed to multiple users using ClickOnce. Each physical install on a users machine will have both the deployed application as well as the `app.config`.  The `app.config` holds credentials for a restricted account for a database.

Is it possible to encrypt data such as credentials for a Db connection in WinForms that is deployed to the masses?  Some users work on laptops offsite, so a network connection wont always be available.  I'm just trying to find out what the best practices are for securing a WinForms application might be in this scenario.

Comment: Do you want to send encrypted password in a file to many users then any user can decrypt it with specified application? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: There are examples of app configs with encrypted sections or specific lines.. what are you specifically struggling with? this question is too broad

Comment: If data is sensitive, then it is a bad idea to store it in the app.config file

Comment: Hi all, I've updated my original question for clarity. :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can save the credentials as an encrypted string in your app.config. SO provides some good examples on how to use the `System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael` symetric algorithm.

This of course requires the same key to encrypt and decrypt the data. That key will be stored in the source code, and .NET sourcecode is not really save, everyone with the ability to use google and use a program with more than one button will be able to find it in the decompiled code and thus, it's only slightly more safe than just having the password not encrypted.

Most important is, that the credentials your app uses to access the database are only allowed to do what the app needs, so not like using SQL Management Studio to oben the DB and being able to reconfigure everything (Saw that once at a customer).